# Adding or retrieving data through Gae datastore 

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Java for deploying datastore on GAE, pls anyone tell me how I can browse the data on the datastore without using localhost?
I am expecting it should be like .appspot.com/something...

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the application administration using this url:

https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=YOURAPPPLICATIONID

Comment: ...or go straight to the datastore with https://appengine.google.com/datastore/explorer?&app_id=YOURAPPLICATIONID

Answer (score 0):

You can find 'Datastore Viewer' on your application dashboard

[Click here for reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_QI4fiXaiE3elpLOGcyMGpha28/edit?usp=sharing)